# Cannot use "my $_" in new version(s) of Perl

Tags: perl

In Perl 5.28.1, the following statement is invalid:

```
>perl
my $_;

Can't use global $_ in "my" at - line 1, near "my $_"
Execution of - aborted due to compilation errors.
```

This worked at least up to Perl 5.16.3. Was this construct removed from Perl, or is this a bug? If this was removed, I consider that a big problem as this basic construct has been heavily used in the past, and it is also demonstrated in the Perl documentation. Neither [Perl history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_5_version_history) does mention such a big change in the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Was this construct removed from Perl, or is this a bug?

From [perldoc perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> $_ is a global variable.
>
> **However, between perl v5.10.0 and v5.24.0, it could be used lexically
>   by writing my $_** . Making $_ refer to the global $_ in the same scope
>   was then possible with our $_ . **This experimental feature was removed**
>   and is now a fatal error, but you may encounter it in older code.

> If this was removed, I consider that a big problem as ...

I think this is not the right place to discuss this, i.e. discussions would not solve your current problem. As ikegami pointed out in the comments: this feature was marked experimental in 5.18 and thus led to warnings for many years. And you probably just need to replace the `my $_` with `local $_` in your code.

Comment: I'd add: Use of `my $_` started warning that it was an experimental feature in 5.18 (even if warnings weren't enabled), giving three years for people to prepare for their removal in 5.24. 5.18 is when the concept of experimental features was first formalized (in the wake of the `switch`/smartmatch/lexical `$_` disaster).

Comment: The perldoc in v5.16 says nothing about that this was an experimental feature. A lot of perl code was written between 2007 (v5.10) and 2016 (v5.24), and even later if you didn't upgrade to the latest version. Actually almost all my code, as I no longer use perl. Now, when I upgraded to the newest perl, many of my utilities written in perl are broken. Without local `$_`, any subroutine can change your `$_` value, which makes `$_` almost unusable.

Comment: @xarx, Yes, it's unfortunate, but the perl devs made huge mistakes in 5.10. This spawned new policies and formal concept of experimental features in 5.18. Lexical `$_` was demoted to experimental at that time, effectively obsoleting it. Due to the problems is caused, and since it wasn't used much, it was removed in 5.24. (switch and smartmaching persist as experimental features to this day, because many are using them despite their broken design.)

Comment: @xarx, Re "*Without local `$_`, any subroutine can change your `$_` value, which makes `$_` almost unusable*", Having to keep using `local $_` (as with ever other punctuation variable) instead of `my $_` doesn't make any subroutine "almost unusable".

Comment: If replacing `my $_` with `local $_` works, that would be a big time-saver. Thanks for the hint. However, the Perlsub docs says: "In general, you should be using `my` instead of `local`, because it's faster and safer." And in Perlfunc docs: "You really probably want to be using `my` instead (of `local`), because `local` isn't what most people think of as 'local'." That's why I didn't use `local` keyword much in my code.

Comment: For unique variables you invent yourself, `my` is best, to make sure it doesn't clash with other code. For the built-in variables, `local` should be used, since what you want really is to change the effect of that variable on other code.

Comment: It seems that blindly replacing `my $_` everywhere with `local $_` helped. Thank a lot!

Comment: @aschepler, Re "_For the built-in variables, `local` should be used_", I'd say that such a rule is oversimplified. E.g. if I have a subroutine that works with global `$_`, and I call it from another subroutine that uses `$_` for local purposes, the first subroutine breaks. Exactly in these situations `my $_` was useful and better suited - because it redefined `$_` only inside the block, not down the call-stack.

Comment: @xarx I believe that comment was in relation to `my` - it's not possible for built-in variables, so the best you can do is use `local`. Otherwise you will be modifying the current value, visible for the caller. `$_` should ever be used for "local purposes", and always localized properly (either thru explicit `local $_` or from implicit one from `foreach`) (except one-liners). If you want to be passing or storing data with global variables, use your own custom instead of built-in ones. If you needed to use `my $_`, what you should have used instead was `my $meaningful_variable_name`.

Comment: @Silvar I understand the consequences of removal of `my $_' from the language. However, `$_' is not _any_ variable, this variable is very special - it allows removal of the variable name from expressions. E.g. instead of `$_ =~ /xxx/` you can write simply `/xxx/`. Hence what you write is surely true, but it's a trivial fact. Moreover, you cannot blindly replace`my` with `local` - usage of  `local` is much more limited and more dangerous, as I've hopefully illustrated in my previous comment.

Comment: @xarx My point was that use of `local $_` is dangerous only sofar as your subroutines are further using `$_` dangerously. If every subroutine localizes it before use, there is no problem.